# How can I do automatically capture changing values in the scenario I have written, what kind of method do I need to develop dynamically framework?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

```
 Scenario: Filtering Test >
 When the User verifies a total of "number" values on the "first" page>
 And the User confirms "number" values on the "second" page >
 And the User checks "number" values on the "last" page>
 Then the User validates that the sum of all the numbers displayed on >
 the screen is accurate
```

---

How can I calculate the sum of these numbers on my screen without disrupting my Cucumber framework? Alternatively, how can I ensure the accuracy of the sum even if it's not visibly displayed on the screen? The placeholder "number" I've used in this example is represented as a String, and this poses an issue when attempting to convert it (with ParseInt) to an int, as it interferes with the functionality of my framework.

My goal is to create a sustainable scenario that dynamically captures variable values from the screen, eliminating the need to manually update these values in the scenario each time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.